# How to move files to the loaded directory in treeview and actual file should be cut/copy from one directory to another loaded directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-forms-designer

I have a treeview made in c sharp windows forms Application in this treeview I have loaded a system directory so treeview shows folders and files so when I drag and move files towards loaded directory in treeview it shows that file is being dropped but actual its not when I restart my program its vanished.. Please help me my source code is below.

```
private void treeView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            TreeNode aNode;
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", false))
            {
                Point apoint;
                TreeNode TargetNode;
                apoint = ((TreeView)sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                TargetNode = ((TreeView)sender).GetNodeAt(apoint);
                aNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode");
                TargetNode.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)aNode.Clone());
                TargetNode.Expand();
                aNode.Remove();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            string[] droppedFiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string file in droppedFiles)
            {
                string filename = getFileName(file);
                string filepath = getFilepath(file);
                MessageBox.Show("You dropped " + filename);
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(filename);
                textBox5.Text = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
                cv.Text = filepath;

                try
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cv.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }

        }
 private void treeView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

Comment: You're just dragging `TreeNodes` around. They can do direct connection to the files and folders you read in the first place. How would you usually move or copy a file? That's how you would do it here.